# Simples Requisição GET

Tags: node.js, get, requisição

Estou tentando consumir uma API do Conselho Federal de Medicina mas até o momento sem sucesso.

Trata-se de uma requisição GET bem simples:
https://portal.cfm.org.br/api_rest_php/api/v1/medicos/buscar_foto/9666/PA

Onde os últimos 2 parâmetros são o CRM do médico e a sigla do Estado (UF).

Estou tentando pelo node.js com o código abaixo:

const url = 'https://portal.cfm.org.br/api_rest_php/api/v1/medicos/buscar_foto/9666/PA'

```
axios.get(url)
    .then(retorno => {
      res.json(retorno.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json(err)
    })
```

O problema é que retorno.data sempre retorna vazio, mas chamando a mesma URL no navegador os dados são retornados corretamente.

O quê estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei replicar o problema e não aconteceu, funciona corretamente. Como não tem seu código todo, não sei se falta algo, veja abaixo:

```js
var url = 'https://portal.cfm.org.br/api_rest_php/api/v1/medicos/buscar_foto/9666/PA';
axios.get(url)
     .then(retorno => {
       console.log(retorno.data);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       res.json(err)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Sugiro inspecionar o que tem em "retorno" para ver o que volta no se request. Tem uma propriedade "status" que te diz se foi sucesso ou não.